# Matlab KNNClassify Consensus

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn, consensus

I use knnclassify consensus. I try find missing values in class label using consensus.

This is my code;

```
Rb = randperm(120);
Rm = randperm(120);

labeled = labeled(Rb,:);
unlabeled = unlabeled(Rm,:);

cnt = 0;
sonuc = zeros(120,1);

for i=1:120
    pred=knnclassify(unlabeled,labeled,labeledClass,10,'correlation','consensus');
    if pred>=1
        cnt=cnt+1;
        sonuc(i)= pred;
    end
end

cnt;
```

and this is my workspace;

my workspace benign and malignant my class values
  http://imgbox.com/EmWvlqnv

Code is not return Error but pred return NaN in all row and return one warning;

```
Warning: Some points in data have small relative standard deviations,
making them effectively constant. Correlation metric may not be appropriate
for these points. 
> In pdist2 at 304
  In ExhaustiveSearcher.knnsearch at 207
  In knnsearch at 142
  In knnclassify at 162
  In CancerKNNConsensus at 11
```

I try Euclidean, Cosine, Cityblock and Correlation.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that some of your data have small std and constant, which will cause some problems when using correlation distance.

The correlation distance in matlab will subtract the mean of the data first. Thus for a constant data vector, subtracting mean will result in a zero vector, and  the correlation of a constant vector with any other data vector is not defined.

My suggestion to fix this problem is as follows:

1. identify these data points based on std, and remove these data with small std before using knn clusfier;
2. normalize your data may also help;
3. try other distance metric.

Hope this is helpful.